# YAML not exiting correctly

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

In my gitlab CI runner I'm setting up the yaml to call a python script. Currently the script fails to connect to an HTTP server (this is expected behavior). The resulting exception is caught in the python script and it exits with a `-1`. However the CI runner hangs indefinitely. What could the problem be?

Comment: YAML doesn't call scripts, there is nothing in the specification that provides this functionality. The program processing the YAML might do such a thing, either by interpreting scalars or by instantiation of objects based on tags (the latter is less common). The YAML tag is inappropriate (as would e.g. be ASCII or UTF-8). The problem could be faulty syntax, faulty assumptions, unreliable network, essentially anything people here can guess (and then some) based on so little *concrete* information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a misunderstanding of how the gitlab ci works. In the `script` tag I was first booting up a system that the hanging executable did work on. When the executable fails it expects the child processes to be cleaned up before proceeding. I was expecting the ci to call into `after_script` which is where I was doing the clean-up.